# Bar chart of logical variables ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've started using ggplot and seem to be able to plot numerical variables but how do I plot a bar chart with the count of a logical variables e.g. `TRUE` (one bar) and `FALSE` (second bar) for `v1` (logical variable) only using ggplot?

```
dataframe <- data.frame(
  v1 = r_sample_logical(10, prob = NULL, name = "Logical" ),
  v2 = r_sample_logical(10, prob = NULL, name = "Logical" )
)
```

```
> dataframe
      v1    v2
1  FALSE FALSE
2   TRUE FALSE
3  FALSE  TRUE
4   TRUE  TRUE
5   TRUE  TRUE
6   TRUE  TRUE
7   TRUE  TRUE
8  FALSE  TRUE
9   TRUE FALSE
10  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `interaction()` function to combine the two columns into one variable that you can put on the x-axis.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dataframe <- data.frame(
  v1 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE),
  v2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(dataframe, aes(interaction(v1, v2))) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>